What would be the stride and offset of this user defined point in PCL?
I want to use the PCL function, getMatrixXfMap, but I don't know what the stride of my point type is.
struct My_Point
{
  PCL_ADD_POINT4D;

  uint8_t    direction;
  uint8_t    type;
  uint8_t    count;
  uint32_t   row;
  uint32_t   col;
  float      intensity;
  uint8_t    index;
  uint8_t    value1;
  float      value2;
  union
  {
    union
    {
      struct
      {
        uint8_t b;
        uint8_t g;
        uint8_t r;
        uint8_t _unused;
      };
      float rgb;
    };
    uint32_t rgba;
  };

  EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
  // ensure proper alignment
} EIGEN_ALIGN16;

I would say I have 14 values so with PCL's definition stride of 14. But I'm not sure how the union affects stride. Also documentation for getMatrixXfMap warns "PointT types are most of the time aligned, so the offsets are not continuous". What does that mean exactly? How do I determine these values?
getMatrixXfMap documentation:
https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#ab9486898ac363e8206829da7c01ea62d

For the sake of anyone else who is trying to make sense of this: The PCL_ADD_POINT4D macro adds 4 floats (x,y,z + padding) on top of the struct. @Isaac: I assume you want to map the x,y,z floats and not anything else?

The stride should be sizeof(My_Point) / sizeof(float). Do not try to guess it yourself.

To untangle that type definition, the macro PCL_ADD_POINT4D expands to PCL_ADD_POINT4D which expands to
#define PCL_ADD_UNION_POINT4D \
  union EIGEN_ALIGN16 { \
    float data[4]; \
    struct { \
      float x; \
      float y; \
      float z; \
    }; \
  };

I assume you want to map the xyz coordinates. The stride (outer stride in Eigen lingo) is defined as multiples of sizeof(T) (in this case float). Since these are the first members in your struct, we don't have to deal with the offset, making the solution simply:
cloud.getMatrixXfMap(3 /*dim*/,
                     sizeof(My_Point) / sizeof(float) /*stride*/,
                     0 /*offset*/);

The offset is also in multiples of sizeof(float), so you could define it as offsetof(My_Point, x)/sizeof(float), assuming the type is compatible with offsetof
As a side note: The mapped matrix type is suboptimal since it doesn't make use of the fact that stride and the inner dimension size are small and fixed at compile time. For performance, you may prefer definitions such as these:
using PclMatrixMap = Eigen::Map<
        Eigen::Matrix3Xf, Eigen::Aligned16,
        Eigen::OuterStride<sizeof(My_Point)/sizeof(float)>>;

using ConstPclMatrixMap = Eigen::Map<
        const Eigen::Matrix3Xf, Eigen::Aligned16,
        Eigen::OuterStride<sizeof(My_Point)/sizeof(float)>>;


ConstPclMatrixMap map(const PointCloud<My_Point>& points) noexcept
{
    return ConstPclMatrixMap(points.data()->data, 3,
            static_cast<Eigen::Index>(points.size()));
}
PclMatrixMap map(PointCloud<My_Point>& points) noexcept
{
    return PclMatrixMap(points.data()->data, 3,
            static_cast<Eigen::Index>(points.size()));
}

You could also use the whole thing as a Matrix4Xf with the fourth padding float included. In general, this will create more efficient code since it directly maps to a single vector register. Otherwise Eigen has to issue two instructions (one half-register, one scalar) per access in order to not touch that fourth entry.
Alternatively you may use that float for something else, e.g. the intensity. However, PCL doesn't do that for its own PointXYZI so I'm not sure if they assume that the padding value can be overwritten in their own code.
